# Windows firewall blocks port connection even it's allowed

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, firewall, vmware-vsphere

I have setup windows firewall rules to allow port 443 and 9000 to be allowed though inbound and outbound connections, and allowed the apache httpd.exe though the firewall as well. But as shown by my firewall log, you can see that both ports are still being actively dropped. Below I have attached screenshots of my firewall rules for both inbound and outbound, my firewall logs showing the connection being dropped, and my IP configuration on the windows server. Notice that I am using virtual machine to do this, I don't know if this has anything to do with my firewall blocking allowed connections.

[Firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G57M1.jpg)

[Firewall logs and IP config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJo8p.jpg)

Comment: Looks like its inbound 443 thats getting blocked, outbound 443 would be if your webserver was connecting to another server. Can you post a screen shot of the config of the inbound 443 rule?

Comment: I believe it's 443 and 9000 inbound gets blocked. Here it is:https://screenshot.net/k8m6zhy

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your virus software that is doing that. Check its rules or check if you can add a rule there. on windows I used to use symantec and it did the same thing.

Comment: Not really, I found a way to disable windows firewall and it worked, however, it still doesn't solve my problem of how windows firewall is dropping packets even though I added the rules to allow it.